# Upload data with image to an api with Excel/csv

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a requirement to upload a bunch of `products`, each product has details like `name`, `description`,`price` and `image`.

The problem I am facing is the image part, image cannot be inserted in a cell.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?